# What values should I assign in SimpleLoraApp.ned to change the code rate in Flora Omnet++?

Tags: inet, flora

I am new to flora Omnet++. I want to change the code rate and see the performance in different scenarios. The default value is set to 4 for LoRaCR parameter, which means code rate is 4/8. If I want to change it to 4/5, 4/6, 4/7, what values should I assign in the SimpleLoraApp.ned ?

In inet is there a related code?

I changed the LoRaCR parameter default value to 2 from 4 just to see whether there is an impact and packet receiving ratio was different.